# how to store and then pass the data coming as dio response in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using flutter and trying to get the OTP from the server. Then sending it to another activity to check the response again.

The first activity is sending the data to the server and the server is sending the response. I have to take the 'id' from the response and send it to another activity where it should be sent to another server API which will send the response "success" or "failure". I have to check and show the respected result.

```
createAlbum(Map<String, dynamic> body)async{
      var dio = Dio();
      try {
        FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap(body);
        var response = await dio.post("http://hiddenmasterminds.com/web/index.php?r=jflipgradtest/createdata", data: formData);
        ident = response.data['id'].toString();
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }

onPressed: (){
                              var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
                              map['name'] = s;
                              map['mobile_number'] = s1;
                              map['pincode'] = s2;
                              map['city'] = s5;
                              map['time_to_contact'] = s3;
                              createAlbum(map);
                              },
```

This is the code I am using for the first activity. I have to take the id from here and send it to another activity. I am sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
createAlbum(Map<String, dynamic> body) async {
    var dio = Dio();
    try {
      FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap(body);
      var response = await dio.post(
          "http://paisecentre.in/pc/web/index.php?r=jflipgradtest/createdata",
          data: formData);
      setState(() {
        ident = response.data['id'].toString();
      });
      print(ident);
      Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => OtpApp(id: ident)));
    }
    catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```